# Count duration of value in vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to count the length of occurrances of a value in a vector such as

```
q <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,1,1,4,4,4)
```

Actual vectors are longer than this, and are time based.  What I would like would be an output for 4 that tells me it occurred for 12 time steps (before the vector changes to 6) and then 3 time steps.  (Not that it occurred 15 times total).

Currently my ideas to do this are pretty inefficient (a loop that looks element by element that I can have stop when it doesn't equal the value I specified).  Can anyone recommend a more efficient method?

Comment: search the rle function

Comment: `with(rle(q), data.frame(values, lengths))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, rle has been very useful.  Is there any straightforward way to get the position when the value started?  From my initial example, I would like to know that 4 started at entry 7 and then again at 30 in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

`x <- with(rle(q), data.frame(values, lengths))` will pull the information that you want (courtesy of d.b. in the comments).

From the R Documentation: `rle` is used to "Compute the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector – or the reverse operation."

`y <- x[x$values == 4, ]` will subset the data frame to include only the value of interest (4). You can then see clearly that 4 ran for 12 times and then later for 3.

Modifying the code will let you check whatever value you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, rle has been very useful.  Is there any straightforward way to get the position when the value started?  From my initial example, I would like to know that 4 started at entry 7 and then again at 30 in the vector.